# How can I redirect os.system() output in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to run something inside a Python file, and i do not want to see in the Python console the run output:

```
os.system("cd ../programs/{0} && ./run".format(project))
```

How can I do it? I tried with subprocess.call() but it does not compile.

Comment: *How* did you try with `subprocess.call()`?

Comment: What do you mean by "subprocess.call() but it does not compile"? Python isn't compiled and the subprocess module is a standard library. So what actually happens when you use it? Because I think using it is your answer right there.

Comment: Also, you aren't actually doing any redirection here. Where do you want to redirect output to?

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Most Python implementations are indeed compiled, just not to native machine code. CPython compiles Python byte code (analogous to Java compiling to Java byte code).

Comment: @chepner Yes, that's true. I meant more in the sense that you don't run a separate compilation step where compilations error and runtime errors are disjunct. In hindsight, this distinction is not necessary for the problem at hand.

Answer (score 3):

Redirecting stdout to `/dev/null`:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['./run'],
                cwd=os.path.join('..', 'programs', project),
                stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

Comment: Also note: `os.path.join('..', 'programs', project)` would be a more canonical way of constructing the path. Or if you like modern Python tools more, `pathlib.Path('..', 'programs', project)`.

Comment: Huh, I never realized `subprocess` had added `DEVNULL`.

Comment: Also, `subprocess.run` is now recommended over `subprocess.call`.

Comment: I have tried to run the following: 
```
subprocess.run(['./run'], cwd=pathlib.Path('..', 'programs', project), stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

Comment: And i get the following error (I have copy only the last part of the error):
'''    subprocess.run(['./run'], cwd=pathlib.Path('..', 'programs', project), stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 423, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1364, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: './run' '''

Comment: @EnriqueGonzález, that typically means your script doesn't have a shebang as its first line. Add one. (`#!/bin/sh` if it's written for POSIX sh, `#!/usr/bin/env bash` to choose the first versions of bash in the PATH, etc).